# Парсинг табличного PDF файла

Tags: node.js, парсер, pdf

Пишу бота на Node JS, для своей группы, с сайта получаю PDF файл с расписанием:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Столкнулся с проблемой, использовал сначала tabula-js, конвертировал в CSV, а после искал по столбцу свою группу, но вдруг, после каникул, в этот раз парсинг изменился и теперь всё вообще не на своих местах, т.е. что-то слиплось, а что-то переместилось. Понятно дело, решение не очень гибкое. Прошу помощи у тех, кто уже парсил PDF файлы.

Нужно найти заголовочную строку с названием группы, а после спускаться вниз и собирать всё, пока не появится строчка с словом "курс", что будет означать, что все предметы собраны.

Т.е. на выходе должен быть результат для группы А-01:

1. Математика Белянина
2. Род. Литература Разумовская
3. Физика Морданова

Прошу помощи, так как уже у самого нет идей, все библиотеки кажутся не подходящими для этого, ибо не получается вытащить нужное для меня и отсеять от другого. Может кто-то знает способ? Видел конвертеры в HTML, но там просто блоки, а не таблица, вытаскивать там только можно по классам, но всё же хотел бы убедиться, есть ли другие способы?

Comment: Не мешало б было прикрепить сюда этот самый csv а то не понятно, какой там выход одна большая таблица или 16 маленьких, но общий выход обычно такой что pdf летит в word а уже word парсится по таблично и по строчно

Comment: Хей, Антон. Спасибо за совет, действительно, PDF в DOCX оказалось хорошим решением. Но не совсем. Я искал либы по парсингу DOCX на Node JS, всё очень печально с этим, только вытаскивание полного текста, это не то, что мне нужно. Решил перевести PDF в HTML, ситуация лучше, но вытащить нужное тоже довольно проблематично. Решил сделать PDF2DOCX2HTML и да, это довольно крутое решение, в плане подачи информации. Использовал для начала API online-convert, всё отлично, но SDK нет. Потом нашел cloudconvert, SDK топ, но переводит довольно на среднем уровне, поэтому остановился на API online-convert.